# CodeIgniter - Query array output three times instead one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Output is wrong , i Got three the same  comment instead only one.
Can anyone help to make only one comment.

Here my view php code:

```
$modelid = "5" ;

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT message FROM message WHERE modelid = '.$modelid.' ');

$row = $query->row(); 

echo $row->message;
```

and my Table:

http://dev.interactive-creation-works.net/Stack/table.png

The controller:

```
        class Comment extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $data['result'] = $this->db->get('message')->result();
        $this->load->view('commentView',$data);

    }
    function insert()
    {

     $this->load->model('commentjquery');
     echo $this->commentjquery->inserttodb();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this query do when you use in mysql? What is your db structure? What is in db?

Comment: sry couldnt posted an image here the link to tghe structure
it should only list the comment message where the modelid 5 is

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: This is apparently a CodeIgniter view, so presumably it's being loaded and used by a controller function. The controller could be the problem, though - mind posting it, dA?

Comment: Wait.  A view?!  NO!  Don't call the database in the view!  Use the models for that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes, that's certainly the correct way to do it. One thing at a time, though.

Comment: ok i post the controller second
i wanted irst discover the query then i want it exlude into the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This view should only show one message, even if you do - for whatever reason, correctly or not - get three messages from the query. You may be loading the view three times in your controller. Try adding some static text to the top and bottom of your view, and see if it shows up multiple times.

Edit:

Now that you've posted the controller, I can see that's not the issue. But I notice you're trying to grab the comments from the database twice - once in the controller and once in the model. The one in the controller is actually the wrong way to do it unless you've implemented an ActiveRecord model for your comments, and you're not using the results anyway.
Another thing I noticed just now is that you're calling `$query->row()` instead of running a foreach over `$query->result()`. Try this:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->message;
}
```

Edit 2: Or maybe it is the problem, if the code snippet you posted isn't the entire view, which seems to be the case.

Comment: Ok the echo of textsample is threetimes theire too

Comment: thank you i found the problem i forget to remove a foreach and the end of the foreach

Comment: ok i will try. at the moment the output is only one time but it gives not all rows out whch have the modelid  5

Comment: Thank your very much , Your Code works i see now all rows with the right modelid. thank you for your time =)

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird that you aren't getting error. It gets weirder when you get three outputs.

Change your query to this.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT message FROM message WHERE modelid = "'.$modelid.'"');
```

Comment: ty for your anwser but i got the solution from user1618143